# upload image with particular width and height in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to add banners from the admin panel. I want to upload images only 1920 width and 700 height images. I don't want to allow if the image width is less then 1920 or bigger than 1920 pixels.

How can I do this? Please help me.

Please check my code.

```
 $banner_config['min_width'] = 1920;
 $banner_config['min_height'] = 700;
```

I tried this but not working

```
 $banner_config['width'] = 1920;
 $banner_config['height'] = 700;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$banner_config['min_width'] = 1920;
$banner_config['min_height'] = 700;
$banner_config['max_width'] = 1920;
$banner_config['max_height'] = 700;
```

For reference: [File Uploading Preferences](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#preferences)